# Is there a way to tell WCF to use security in the request, but ignore it on the response?

Tags: wcf, soap, axis

We have to connect to a third party SOAP service and we are using WCF to do so.  The service was developed using Apache AXIS, and we have no control over it, and have no influence to change how it works.
The problem we are seeing is that it expects the requests to be formatted using Web Services Security, so we are doing all the correct signing, etc.  The response from the 3rd party however, is not secured.  If we sniff the wire, we see the response coming back fine (albeit without any timestamp, signature etc.).
The underlying .NET components throw this as an error because it sees it as a security issue, so we don't actually receive the soap response as such.  Is there any way to configure the WCF framework for sending secure requests, but not to expect security fields in the response?  Looking at the OASIS specs, it doesn't appear to mandate that the responses must be secure.

For information, here's the exception we see:

The exception we receive is:

```
System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException was caught
  Message="Security processor was unable to find a security header in the message. This might be because the message is an unsecured fault or because there is a binding mismatch between the communicating parties.   This can occur if the service is configured for security and the client is not using security."
  Source="mscorlib"
  StackTrace:
    Server stack trace:
       at System.ServiceModel.Security.TransportSecurityProtocol.VerifyIncomingMessageCore(Message& message, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Security.TransportSecurityProtocol.VerifyIncomingMessage(Message& message, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityProtocol.VerifyIncomingMessage(Message& message, TimeSpan timeout, SecurityProtocolCorrelationState[] correlationStates)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.SecurityRequestChannel.ProcessReply(Message reply, SecurityProtocolCorrelationState correlationState, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.SecurityRequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
```

Incidentally, I've seen plenty of posts stating that if you leave the timestamp out, then the security fields will not be expected.  This is not an option - The service we are communicating with mandates timestamps.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft has a hotfix for this functionality now.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971493

Comment: Also note that this patch is part of .NET 3.5 SP1

Comment: There is also a hotfix for .NET 3.0, but is only on request. Also the hotfix for 3.5 SP1 has been rolled up in Windows 7 SP1 (and also for Server 2008)

Answer (score 2):

Funny you should ask this question. I asked Microsoft how to do this about a year ago. At the time, using .NET 3.0, it was not possible. Not sure if that changed in the 3.5 world. But, no, there was no physical way of adding security to the request and leaving the response empty.

At my previous employer we used a model that required a WS-Security header using certificates on the request but the response was left unsecured.

You can do this with ASMX web services and WSE, but not with WCF v3.0.

Answer (score 2):

There is a good chance you will not be able to get away with configuration alone. I had to do some integration work with Axxis (our end was WSE3 -- WCF's ancestor), and I had to write some code and stick it into WSE3's pipeline to massage the response from Axxis before passing it over to WSE3. The good news is that adding these handlers to the pipeline is fairly straightforward, and once in the handler, you just get an instance of a SoapMessage, and can do anything you want with it (like removing the timestamp, for example)